# How to mouse hover then need to click on the tab- Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image]
Working on selenium webdriver First i want the mouse need to hover to tab which is shown in image. from **Age** to **Time to Resolve**. Using **Java**.

```
if(existsElement("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution"));// Problem in this line
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();//
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;// This is exactly opening the page
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));// This is exactly opening the page
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
```

Here is the HTML tag

```
<a id="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" class=" ext-pr-backlog-evolution" name="ext-pr-backlog-evolution" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prbacklogevolutiontendency/reports/type/default/">Overview & Evolution</a>
```

In the Image upto **Problem Reports(PR)** the mouse is hovering when trying to click on **Overview and Evloution** tab it is moving to **Ticket** tab but the **Overview and Evloution** page is opening. Exactly it is opening the tab but not hovering and clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using hardcoded sleep because it slows your test.

How about using the implicit wait?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

What it does:

1. When the element is present, continue on your test
2. When the element is not present (when the site is slow), it will throw a timeout.

That is much better test so you know why your test fails

More info here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 1):

This error comes if the element is not visible or enabled.

Here is two points from me
1. If you are hovering then properly using selenium just check if the element is visible or enabled.
2. Or use JavascriptExecutor. It can click on hidden elements with out opening them.

```
(JavascriptExecutor(webdriver)).executeScript("document.getElementsById('ext-pr-backlog-evolution').click();");
```

Comment: Buddy. You have to change the code as per your use. This is the example. like "webdriver" will be "driver" in your case. For using javascriptexecutor import "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor"

Comment: Please suggest me any solution or sample example