# How can i create mouse event for clicking a tab- Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium, tabs

Working with **Selenium WebDriver** and **Java**. I have tab name called **PR Per Product**.
I have many tabs under **PR Reports** tab.. In that PR tab i used

```
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
```

But the same format i tried to click **PR Per Product** tab it is clicking some other tab. The element is targeting through the ID.

```
<a id="ext-pr-domain" class=" ext-pr-domain" name="ext-pr-domain" href="https://10.4.16.159/extranet_prperdomain/reports/">Per Prod/SW Pack/RDT Group</a>
```

If i use this method it is exactly clicking the tab. But the problem it is not hovering and clicking.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("Per Prod/SW Pack/RDT Group") ));
```

Please help me for the issue..

Comment: Look at [question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276350/how-to-mouse-hover-then-need-to-click-on-the-tab-selenium-webdriver?rq=1). Could help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried what ever given in that question its is not helping me.. please give me some solution

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you have to build the action also. Try

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
```

or if you need to click in order to make it visible:

```
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).click().build().perform();
```